# npm install creating hurdle getting python env error

Tags: python, npm, npm-install, web3py

```
gyp ERR! configure error
gyp ERR! stack Error: Can't find Python executable "C:\Programs\Python2.7\python2.7.exe", you can set the PYTHON env variable.
gyp ERR! stack     at PythonFinder.failNoPython (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\configure.js:483:19)
gyp ERR! stack     at PythonFinder.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\configure.js:508:16)
gyp ERR! stack     at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\graceful-fs\polyfills.js:284:29
gyp ERR! stack     at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:152:21)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.15063
gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd G:\project\kanwat infotech\new project\node_modules\scrypt
gyp ERR! node -v v8.11.1
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.6.2
gyp ERR! not ok
npm WARN new project No description
npm WARN new project No repository field.
npm WARN new project No license field.

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! scrypt@6.0.3 install: `node-gyp rebuild`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the scrypt@6.0.3 install script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Sandeep\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2018-05-07T19_54_26_289Z-debug.log
```

I am stuck with this error in installing web3 package.

Answer (score 0):

From the looks of the error message you don't have python installed **OR** PYTHON env is set to a wrong location.

> Error: Can't find Python executable "C:\Programs\Python2.7\python2.7.exe", you can set the PYTHON env variable

check if below command works and install pythong if not.

```
python --version
```